# How handle two document type?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm designing my `documents` table for Document Management System. I have a many to many relationship of `users` and `documents` with a junction table of `usersdocuments` I need opinion from others because I have a two type of document which I'm gonna implement.

- Request
- Resolution

My plan here I'm  gonna put them inside in `documents` table instead of doing two table. I need determine which document type does the user is using? What kind of data type I'm gonna use to implement this?

[image: SC]

Comment: Don't use terms on like 'gonna' on SO. It's lazy and offensive. Well, I'm offended anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What kind of data type I'm gonna use to implement this? To avoid
>   confusion using BIT.

Yes you can use [`BIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-field-literals.html) as the datatype for that column like

```
IsRequest BIT(1)
```

Since there is only two types `Request` and `Resolution` you can figure it out by saying

```
select * from documents
where IsRequest = 'true'; // want to fetch only Request type
```

Comment: If `IsRequest` is equals to `'false';` so this will be Resolution type? What's the value of `(1)` in `BIT`?

Comment: @Francisunoxx, Yes if false then resolution. See the linked document `(N)` determines no.of bits.